# Problems with loop

Tags: c#, loops

I'm still in the learning stages of `C#` and I need some help with my program.

My program is supposed to work like this, I have 6 salesmen, and in the console I will write information about them`(name, sold items etc)`. How can I make it loop 6 times (one for each salesmen)?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) (Couldn't come up with more than this)
            { 

            salesmen[] seller = new salesmen[6];

            //Salesmen name
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
            salesmen[0].namn = System.Console.ReadLine();

            //Birth certificate
            Console.WriteLine("Enter birth certificate: ");
            salesmen[0].birthvertificate = Console.ReadLine();

            //Enter district
            Console.WriteLine("Enter district: ");
            salesmen[0].district = Console.ReadLine();

            //Enter solditems
            Console.WriteLine("Enter solditems: ");
            salesmen[0].solditems = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            //Calculates what level each salesmen has reached
            if (salesmen[0].solditems < 50)
                salesmen[0].level = 1;

            if (salesmen[0].solditems >= 50 && salesmen[0].solitems < 99)
                salesmen[0].level = 2;

            if (salesmen[0].solitems >= 100 && salesmen[0].solditems < 199)
                salesmen[0].level = 3;

            if (salesmen[0].solditems > 199)
                salesmen[0].level = 4;
```

Comment: Your "i" loop variable will then go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. How can you use this variable to print out each saleman's information? Perhaps the variable can be used to index the salesmen array.

Comment: You also create a brand new array of 6 salesmen every iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are only changing the `salesmen[0]`. In order to use the loop replace all `salesmen[0]` with `salesmen[i]`.

Comment: and move `salesmen[] seller = new salesmen[6];` before the loop

Answer (score 0):

Is the code you provided the full code you are using? After quickly glancing at it, I noticed that your array declaration is inside the for loop, initializing the array 6 times with an empty one.

And as [@Drenguin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953571/drenguin) stated, you should use an index (in this case i) to modify the right salesman.

I also noticed that you wrote

```
salesmen[0].namn
```

instead of

```
salesmen[0].name
```

and although your code works, the correct spelling might be more readable.

Comment: Sorry for the spelling, had to translate the code from swedish to english so I could get some help with it. Will test the code when I get home and report back. Thanks!